# sql - insert between two record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Record is a table in my database and 'Code' is primary key.

Code - > `1000-1001-1002-1003-1004 ...`

If 1002 delete `1000-1001-1003-1004`

If have a new record search 'Code' and find pos,for example
`1000-1001-1003-1004` and new record primary key will `1002`.

But not a pos between two record primary key will `1005`.

How can I do this ?

Comment: You need a structure so you manually keep track of "open gaps" in your sequence. So you insert values into that when deleting and remove values from that when inserting.

Comment: You don't want to re-use primary keys.  SQL Server is doing the right thing by leaving the gap.  If you want the behavior you specify, you'll have to write a trigger.

Comment: I think you need to explain *why* you need to do this. My guess is that you are either a.) deleting a record when you should be updating it, or b.) assigning a semantic value to an identity, which is an antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

On the rare occasion I need to insert a value that is contrary to the IDENTITY, I do something like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[Table] ON  --Allow insert of specific ID values
INSERT INTO dbo.[Table] ...
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[Table] OFF --Revert to auto-generated ID values
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code primary key column is also an identity column which auto-increasing at every insertion of new record. You should leave it as it is. Do not re-use primary key as it could impact the integrity of your database. If possible, try not to delete records, you can add a column to the table that keep track of status of each record by marking them as active or inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are using a natural key as your table's primary key. That is okay, and of course you can delete such a record and later re-use that key. An example would be an employee table where the key is the employee number which might get re-used some time.

Only, you use the SQL Server's auto increment feature, which you would do for ID based tables, but not for natural keys.

In SQL Server this type of auto increment column is called IDENTITY. Remove that property and care yourself about administrating the key codes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply insert a record in between records when using a `IDENTITY`-column, `IDENTITY` means the value of that key is automatically generated by the database.

However, I interpret your problem to be not so much about inserting new records, but that you cannot tell the index of a row inside a result set if you delete a row inside that set and ids following that row now are fragmented.

Well, as pointed out in the comments and other answers, reusing primary keys is generally a bad idea, you should have your logic as agnostic to the values of your keys as possible.

That said, of course if you have a primary key that has a numeric type, ordering by that can make sense in a lot of scenarios, however if you want to tell the position of a row inside a set without using the index itself I'd recommend you to use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186734.aspx):

Here is a [simple sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fea97/2) declaring a table, deleting one row and still showing the correct index (row number) of each row inside that set without resetting or reusing primary keys:

```
DECLARE @RowOrderTest TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), Value NVARCHAR(15));

INSERT INTO @RowOrderTest (Value)
    SELECT 'dummy'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dummy'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dummy'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dummy'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dummy'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dummy'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dummy'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dummy'

DELETE @RowOrderTest WHERE ID = 5

SELECT ID, Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) FROM @RowOrderTest
```

If you really need to insert a row with a (in advance) known key value, dont use `IDENTITY`-columns at all, or switch off the automatic behaviour using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[Table] ON` before and `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[Table] OFF` after your row insertion